# using canvas drawing square and triangle with customize color when click bottton

Tags: canvas, html5-canvas

I Have the following code :

```
<html>
 <head>


 </head>
 <body>
    <canvas id="canvasId" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
    <script>
function square() {

  var ctx = document.getElementById('canvasId').getContext('2d');
  var col= document.getElementById("clr");
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.rect(10, 10, 70, 70);
      ctx.fillStyle = 'yellow';
      ctx.fill();
      ctx.lineWidth = 2;
      ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
      ctx.stroke();

}
function triangle () {

      var canvas = document.getElementById('canvasId');
      var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
        var col= document.getElementById("clr");
      context.beginPath();
      context.rect(85, 80, 200, 100);
      context.fillStyle = 'yellow';
      context.fill();
      context.lineWidth = 2;
      context.strokeStyle = 'black';
      context.stroke();

}

    </script>
  <p>Color <input type="color" id="clr" value="" /></p>
  <input type="button" value="square" onclick="square()" />
  <input type="button" value="triangle" onclick="triangle()" />
 </body>
</html>
```

I have a problem on this question, I want when the user choose the color and click on square or triangle, it will draw it with the color that he/she choose, what should I change and add ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to replace the second `rect(...)` call with something that actually draws a triangle, and you can easily get the color from the input field by accessing its `value` attribute.

[Click here for my fork of your jsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/amullins/nqm8b/7/)

The relevant lines for accessing the input value are here:

```
var col= document.getElementById("clr");
ctx.fillStyle = col.value;
```

Now for the triangle drawing (assuming you wanted an isosceles triangle to fit the original rectangle):

```
context.beginPath();
context.moveTo(85, 180);
context.lineTo(185, 80);
context.lineTo(285, 180);
context.closePath();
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a example in http://jsfiddle.net/rcondori/3gmosgq7/

this example is for trapezoids...

```
function isInsideBox(x, y, x1, x2, y1, y2) {
var a = getValueA(x1, x2, y1, y2);
var b = getValueB(x1, y1, a);
var auxY = (a * x) + b;
if (auxY <= y) {
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
}
function getValueA(x1, x2, y1, y2) {
return ((y1 - y2) / (x1 - x2));
}
function getValueB(x1, y1, a) {
return (y1 - (a * x1));
}
```

Comment: hey ron, great answer, please note a bug for anyone that has trouble using this:  if (y > element.y1 && y < element.y3 && x > element.x1 && x < element.x2 && element.evento.has) becomes  if (y > element.y1 && y < (elemTop+element.y3) && x > element.x1 && x < element.x2 && element.evento.has) ; Otherwise, if the canvas is not the first element on page doesn't work. Hope it helps