# how best make this solution javaScript or canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas

[image: i want draw this triangle with active regions]

triangle with active regions with support other resolution any ideas?
Regions links with other pages.
I want build this construction, tell me the right way

Comment: _"any ideas?"_ To do what? You did not explain your problem clearly, you just talked about "triangles", "regions", "pages". Please give us more details, and post the code you have so far if you tried anything. I doubt that anybody would be able to answer with only that info.

Comment: i'm sorry my english not so good, simple i want build this construction , and i can't choose better solution

Comment: _"build this construction"_. Sure, but what should this _construction_ do once it's _built_? Right now, it's just an image, and we don't know what it is supposed to do, or what should be in place of "1", "2" and "3"... Anyway, if you want an answer, you will probably have to give more explanations.

Comment: within the areas of the image will be in the form of links

Comment: "java or canvas" you mean javaSCRIPT maybe ? But canvas is javascript too . My answer is coming soon

Comment: yes Benjamin i mean javaScript ... my mistake ) and thank you! waiting for your reply

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FIRST STEP : triangle

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<canvas id="myCanvas" width="300" height="300" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.</canvas>

<script>

var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

ctx.beginPath();              
ctx.lineWidth = "1";
ctx.strokeStyle = "#d3d3d3";  // Green path

ctx.moveTo(from_x_1, from_y_1);
ctx.lineTo(to_x_1, to_y_1);

ctx.moveTo(from_x_2, from_y_2);
ctx.lineTo(to_x_2, to_y_2);


ctx.moveTo(from_x_3, from_y_3);
ctx.lineTo(to_x_3, to_y_3);

ctx.stroke();  // Draw it


</script>

</body>
</html>
```

You just have to remplace from_x_n with real value.

SECOND STOP : detect click

```
c.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    console.log(event.pageX);
    console.log(event.pageY);

    //here you must check x and y
});
```

to check click visit this link : [using canvas drawing square and triangle with customize color when click bottton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14418698/using-canvas-drawing-square-and-triangle-with-customize-color-when-click-bottton) and specially http://jsfiddle.net/rcondori/3gmosgq7/